# xml feed in classic asp using vb script

Tags: xml, asp-classic, vbscript

```
response.ContentType="text/xml"

response.write("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""iso-8859-1""?>
```

And this throws an error:

```
error on line 9 at column 6: XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your .asp file with the following lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<% Response.ContentType = "text/xml" %>
```

**OR**

with the following lines (**everything in the same line**):

```
<% Response.ContentType = "text/xml" %><?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
```

Comment: Can you provide us the whole .asp file (with the modifications I proposed you)? Do you have other XML declarations in your file?

Comment: Don't let any extra space before the lines I have written.

Comment: your code worked but now got a new error.error on line 1 at column 373: AttValue: " or ' expected the line is:response.write("<url><![CDATA["&Recordset("ContactWebAddres")&"]]></url>")

Comment: What is the value of `Recordset("ContactWebAddres")`?